# How to get dd to print transfer stats in MacOS?

Tags: macos, shell, signals, posix

For MacOS (Mavericks), I am making a shell script to gather transfer stats over time for command `dd`.

The manual page says:

> If dd receives a SIGINFO (see the status argument for stty(1)) signal,
>   the current input and output block counts will be written to the
>   standard error output in the same format as the standard completion
>   message.

Therefore, just like in Linux, I tried:

```
kill -INFO <pid_of_dd>
```

The command completes successfully with status 0, however the terminal in which `dd` process connected to, there is no stats information in standard output/standard error.

So what is the correct way to get `dd` to print stats in its output?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems to work for me:

```
$ dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/null bs=1k &
[1] 33990
$ kill -INFO 33990
4787784+0 records in
4787784+0 records out
4902690816 bytes transferred in 4.260769 secs (1150658706 bytes/sec)
$ kill -INFO 33990
8357846+0 records in
8357846+0 records out
8558434304 bytes transferred in 7.428820 secs (1152058392 bytes/sec)
$ kill 33990
$ ps
  PID TTY           TIME CMD
 1342 ttys000    0:00.02 -bash
 2290 ttys001    0:00.17 -bash
[1]+  Terminated: 15          dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/null bs=1k
$
```

Comment: Thanks very much, later I realized that `kill` returned status 0 but did not send the signal to `dd` because `dd` was owned by root. Merry Christmas.

Answer (score 39):

You can also press Ctrl+T in the Terminal tab to get the same behavior:

```
MacBook-Pro:~ $ dd if=~/source_image.dmg of=/dev/disk1
load: 0.87  cmd: dd 7229 uninterruptible 0.21u 3.91s
265809+0 records in
265808+0 records out
136093696 bytes transferred in 131.170628 secs (1037532 bytes/sec)
load: 0.99  cmd: dd 7229 uninterruptible 0.32u 5.89s
415769+0 records in
415768+0 records out
212873216 bytes transferred in 203.357068 secs (1046795 bytes/sec)
```

Comment: This is the simplest and easiest to remember solution. Thank you!

Comment: Very helpful and easy to remember. Thanks

Comment: No matter what I do, nothing actually prints out the stats

Comment: How did I not know this for so long? So awesome a much easier to remember. Why is it not more common knowledge?

Answer (score 3):

I also found via [commandlinefu](http://www.commandlinefu.com/commands/view/5440/check-the-status-of-dd-in-progress-os-x) that you can also do:

```
killall -INFO dd
```

If you had to run `sudo dd` to start `dd` you might try:

```
sudo killall -INFO dd
```

Also, I started `dd` in the background and with `nohup` so when I ran `sudo killall -INFO dd` and got nothing back for output I had to remember to go and look at the `nohup.out` file because that is where the response was logged to.

Worked great on OS X Mavericks.

Comment: where was this nohup.out? i dont see it in the same dir as I run dd from.

Answer (score 1):

You can press Ctrl+T while the `dd` command is running or, to have a nice **progress bar**, you can install `pv` (pipe viewer) with homebrew:

```
brew install pv
```

and then place pv in between

```
dd if=diskimage.img | pv | dd of=/dev/disk2
```

**example output 1**

```
    18MB 0:00:11 [1.70MiB/s] [      <=>                          ]
```

(with size of transferred data, elapsed time and speed)

---

### Progress bar and ETA

you can also input the size of the image (16GB in this example), to have :

```
dd if=diskimage.img | pv -s 16G | dd of=/dev/disk2
```

**example output 2** (with also progress bar and estimated time):

```
    1.61GiB 0:12:19 [2.82MiB/s] [===>                 ] 10% ETA 1:50:25
```